# What is the proper way to shutdown threads when tomcat closes?

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, web-applications, servlets, log4j

I am trying to shutdown threads when Tomcat is being shutdown.
Specifically I am trying to shutdown log4j watchdog (for filechanges) and also I am trying to shutdown an executor which uses a class in my web app.
On shutdown I see exceptions in Catalina.out.
For Log4J I see:

> INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
>   already.  Could not load org.apache.log4j.helpers.NullEnumeration.
>   The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for
>   debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which
>   caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact. Throwable
>   occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1587)
>           at   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
>           at org.apache.log4j.Category.getAllAppenders(Category.java:413)
>           at org.apache.log4j.Category.closeNestedAppenders(Category.java:226)
>           at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.shutdown(Hierarchy.java:467)
>           at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown(LogManager.java:267)
>           at com.listeners.myListener$1.run(myListener.java:232)
>   Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.apache.log4j.helpers.NullEnumeration
>           at org.apache.log4j.Category.getAllAppenders(Category.java:413)
>           at org.apache.log4j.Category.closeNestedAppenders(Category.java:226)
>           at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.shutdown(Hierarchy.java:467)
>           at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown(LogManager.java:267)

And for the executor part:

> INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
>   already.  Could not load com.my.class.SomeClass.  The eventual
>   following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging
>   purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused
>   the illegal access, and has no functional impact. Throwable occurred:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1587)
>           at   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
>           at 
>   Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.my.class.SomeClass

What I am doing is in `ServletContextListener` on `contextDestroyed` I have added shutdown hooks as follows:

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  

         Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){  
            @Override  
            public void run(){  
                LogManager.shutdown();                  
            }  
         });  

    } 





 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){  
            @Override  
            public void run(){  
                SomeClass.updater.shutdown();  
            }  
        });  

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why do I get exceptions?

**UPDATE:**
`SomeClass.updater` is a `public static ScheduledExecutorService`.
`LogManager` is `org.apache.log4j.LogManager`

**UPDATE2:**
After following the answer from BGR I do directly

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  

            SomeClass.updater.shutdown();  

        }
```

and

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  

                LogManager.shutdown();                  

        }
```

I don't get exception from Log4j but I get the following exception for `SomeClass.updater` which is a `public static ScheduledExecutorService`:

> INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
>   already.  Could not load java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.  The
>   eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for
>   debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which
>   caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact. Throwable
>   occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1587)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)

Why? Are the classes already been garbage collected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would register shutdown hooks in the init() method of the servlet rather than contextDetroyed(), but anyway, why do you need Shutdown hooks in the first place?

Can't you just call `SomeClass.updater.shutdown();`directly in the contextDestroyed() method ?

**EDIT**

`contextDestroyed()` of the listener is to late for the executor service. As stated in the javadoc *All servlets and filters will have been destroyed* **before** *any ServletContextListeners are notified of context destruction.*

whereas overriding the servlet `destroy()` should be OK as according to the javadoc *This method gives the servlet an opportunity to clean up any resources that are being held (for example, memory, file handles,* **threads**...

```
@Override
public void destroy(  ) {


        myThreadExecutor.shutdown();

        super.destroy(  );
}
```

Comment: I thought to use shutdown hooks so that I am sure they get called when JVM shuts down

Comment: Trust your container :-). In any case, register them early on; I would go for the servlet init() method.

Comment: Jim, can you call `SomeClass.updater.shutdown();` in the destroy() method of the Servlet directly (not in the listener where it is 'too late'). Per the javadoc of destroy() *This method gives the servlet an opportunity to clean up any resources that are being held (for example, memory, file handles, threads) and make sure that any persistent state is synchronized with the servlet's current state in memory.*

Comment: As far as I can tell, `destroy()` is not guaranteed to execute to completion. i.e. Tomcat will call `destroy()` and then shortly after terminate, not considering if `destroy()` completed.

Answer (score 2):

Calling

```
LogManager.shutdown();
```

in the contextDestroyed() method is the first step but the ExecutorService does not close immediately. You are getting the exceptions because the ExecutorService threads are still running after the contextDestroyed() method returns. You need to do:

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  
    LogManager.shutdown();
    if(LogManager.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) == false) {
        LogManager.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

This way the thread pool has closed and stopped all threads when contextDestroyed() exits.